# Password verify bcrypt, can't seem to match database

Tags: php, sql, bcrypt, password-encryption

i'm trying to make the password_verify match the crypt password in the database, but i'm having a problem, it seems it doesn't match.

I already search for this and i've found that i need to use VARCHAR with a maximum length of 255 and still doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
if( isset($_POST['bG9n']) && "bG9naW4") {

  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $pass= $_POST['pass'];
if($pass) {
        $crypt = password_hash($pass,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $decrypt = password_verify($pass,$crypt);
    }
    if(password_verify($pass,$crypt)) {
        echo "Sucess"; // It does echo Sucess 
    }
if (!empty($email) && !empty($pass) && filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && password_verify($pass,$crypt)) {

    $sql = "SELECT email, pass FROM clientes WHERE email ='$email' AND pass = '$decrypt' ";
    $query = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $count = $query->rowCount();
        if($count  == 1){
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['pass'] = $decrypt;
                header("Location: home.php");
        }

        else {

            echo "<BR>Error";

        }

    }
```

Probably is an easy fix but i can't seem to find what's wrong.

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest reading the [documentation](http://php.net/password). This looks quite wrong. E.g. how you got to the idea that password_verify returns an unhashed password I have no idea.

Comment: you're going about it the wrong way. You're trying to check against `$decrypt = password_verify($pass,$crypt);` in your query `AND pass = '$decrypt'` and using way too many `password_verify()`'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a normal behaviour. Hash with `bcrypt` is not deterministic, it differs from launch to launch, so you can't query it.

You have to check if it matches not via `mysql` but via `php`.

So, first get it from database, then `$isVerified = password_verify($pass, $hashFromDB);`